# JointJS: Create collapsible tree hierarchy in left stencil section of Rappid example code

Tags: jointjs, rappid

We want to create a collapsible tree structure in the stencil section of the Rappid example code "KitchenSink". The tree will be populated from a graph database and we want the user to be able to click on different levels of the tree to show and collapse the levels.

We were wondering if anyone has tried something similar on the Rappid "KitchenSink" example code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please add some code you tried along with the errors you got and the expected result. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking a better received question next time.